# Botones de acciones en primera columna - Datatables

Tags: php, javascript, datatables, server-side-rendering

Tengo una tabla que hice con Datatables, server side, el cual me arroja un listado con una botonera de acciones, la cual funciona sin ningun problema:

[image: datatable_server_side]

El detalle, es que al querer colocar la botonera de acciones en la primera columna, me arroja error datatables y queda en estado "Procesando".

Mi script es este (**app.js**):

```
var serverSide = $("#serverSide").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "rowReorder": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "ajax/serverside.php",
            "type": "post",
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            { orderable: false, targets: 0 }, // No asignamos orden a columna Actions
        ],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Actions" },
            { "data": "Nombre" },
            { "data": "Apellido" },
            { "data": "Email" },
            { "data": "Genero" }
        ],
        "language": spanishTraduction
    });
```

Y desde php envio la informacion:

public function dataUsersDatatables($draw, $where, $params){

```
        $dataUsers = [];
        $users = $this->crud->serverSide($where, $params);

        if ($users[0] == 1) {

            $totalRecords = $users[1][0];
            $totalRecordsFiltered = $users[2][0];

            foreach ($users[3] as $key => $user) {
                $dataRows[$key]["#"] = ($key+1);
                $dataRows[$key]["Nombre"] = $user->Nombre;
                $dataRows[$key]["Apellido"] = $user->Apellido;
                $dataRows[$key]["Email"] = $user->Email;
                $dataRows[$key]["Genero"] = $user->Genero;
                $dataRows[$key]["Actions"] = "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>";
            }

            $dataUsers = array(
                "draw"                  => $draw,
                "iTotalRecords"         => intval($totalRecords),
                "iTotalDisplayRecords"  => intval($totalRecordsFiltered),
                "aaData"                => $dataRows
            );

        }

        return $dataUsers;

    }
```

Tendre que hacer algun cambio? Al querer usar un formato distinto en la primera fila, debo realizar otra operacion? No tengo idea, espero me puedan ayudar.

PD: Adjunto la captura del error:

[image: Error 2]

PD2: Aqui agrego un ejemplo del json que recibo en la respuesta de php. Revise y segun datatable, tengo un error en la respuesta del Json (DataTables warning: table id=serverSide - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1):

```
{
  "draw": "1",
  "recordsTotal": 1000,
  "recordsFiltered": 1000,
  "data": [
    {
      "Nombre": "Abramo",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Sayton",
      "Email": "asaytonnd@istockphoto.com",
      "Genero": "Male"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Addie",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Robilliard",
      "Email": "arobilliardnt@state.gov",
      "Genero": "Female"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Addie",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Thorley",
      "Email": "athorleynz@etsy.com",
      "Genero": "Female"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Addy",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Samme",
      "Email": "asamme4d@mtv.com",
      "Genero": "Female"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Adeline",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Mitro",
      "Email": "amitroju@examiner.com",
      "Genero": "Female"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Adoree",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Davydenko",
      "Email": "adavydenko2m@goo.gl",
      "Genero": "Female"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Aggi",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Houson",
      "Email": "ahousoncy@moonfruit.com",
      "Genero": "Female"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Aggie",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Backe",
      "Email": "abackern@biblegateway.com",
      "Genero": "Female"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Agnes",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Viccars",
      "Email": "aviccarse@slideshare.net",
      "Genero": "Female"
    },
    {
      "Nombre": "Agnese",
      "Botonera": "<div class='btn-group'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='btn btn-info'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a><button class='btn btn-danger ml-2'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></div>",
      "Apellido": "Schubuser",
      "Email": "aschubuser21@utexas.edu",
      "Genero": "Female"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: En este código no estás colocando Acciones como primera columna, sino como última. En la definición de `columns` solo pon `{ "data": "Actions" }` como primer elemento y debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Triby, cono lo comente mas arriba, hice ese cambio y datatables de arroja error y queda sin mostrar nada en la tabla y mostrando el mensaje de "Procesando"...

Comment: Intenta primero enviando un valor vacío para esa columna, como solo estás incluyendo HTML, sin variables, perfectamente puedes asignar [contenido por defecto](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) al crear la tabla.

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo, envie vacio para esa columna y me sigue arrojando error... Se me ocurrio cambiarla de posicion, a la segunda columna, y no me arroja ningun error y muestra toda la columna con elementos vacios, de hecho, hasta aplique render en la segunda columna y sin dramas.... Esto me hace pensar que algo esta impidiendo en la primera columna en datatable que uno pueda agregar elementos que no sean valores, como html u aplicar render... Sinceramente no entiendo.

Comment: Claro que se puede, lo único que necesitas es definir bien las columnas.

Comment: Tienes algun ejemplo que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Actualice mi post, adjunte la respuesta Json que recibo y que datatable me arroja un error en la respuesta.

Comment: El problema es que estás devolviendo datos que no corresponden, PHP debería devolver solo un arreglo de objetos (`data`), sin otras propiedades; o bien, especificar dónde se encuentra ese arreglo, después de `"rowReorder: true,"` agrega esta línea: `"dataSrc": "data",` Referencia: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc

Comment: Ya encontre solucion! Mas abajo explico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la solucion a mi problema!

Era un detalle super simple. Datatables ordena por defecto desde la primera columna, por ende, a "server side" manda el parametro `['order'][0]['column']`, y ese parametro se usa en la query de myslq, entonces, al ejecutar la query, estoy mandando los parametros que se encuetran en la botonera (todos los div, anclas y botones), lo cual obviamente dara error y por eso no devuelve datos.

Asi que la forma sencilla de corregirlo, es configurar en el script, que el orden por defecto sea desde la segunda columna, y al mismo tiempo, que la primera columna no realice filtro alguno, quedando entonces de esta forma:

```
var serverSide = $("#serverSide").DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]], // Aqui establecemos el orden
        "ajax": {
            "url": "ajax/serverside.php",
            "type": "post"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            { orderable: false, targets: 0 }, // No asignamos orden en primera columna
        ],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Botonera" },
            { "data": "Nombre" },
            { "data": "Apellido" },
            { "data": "Email" },
            { "data": "Genero" }
        ],
        "language": spanishTraduction
    });
```

Espero se haya entendido y de plano gracias a Triby por ir aconsejandome.